# CSS Skin and Style for GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
 <tr>

            <td>

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelKitsMaster" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdvSearch_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="ClinicalRate">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"
                                            CommandName="Select" onclick="RadioCheck(this);" />
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"
                                            Value='<%#Eval("ClinicalRate") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Name"
                                    HeaderText="SubContractor Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ID"
                                    HeaderText="SubContractor ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Title"
                                    HeaderText="Title" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Address"
                                    HeaderText="Address" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>

                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

In the above grid view I do not have any style or css class for the grid view but my grid view shows like below ...

please advise what is  wrong with the grid view css and how should apply a regular or classic style to the grid view

[image]

Comment: Could be correct if the data is all null/blank.

Comment: when I higlight the grid I see all the data present in the grid.All the rows has databut the color is just dominating it and that is what I dont know why?..

Comment: It has to be set somewhere, whether an element, page, stylesheet, master page, or something.  Default web page is white.  Somewhere I think the background is set to black.  You could just set Background="White" on the GridView and you should at least be able to see the data.